# Trying to create a self executable jar file that will display a GUI slide show

Tags: java, user-interface, file-io, jar

I wrote a program in java that uses a GUI the display a slide show of images and display quotes. I am using command lines in the terminal on a mac. I am trying to create a self executable jar file that will run this program on any computer its on. I have been met with my CS professor a bunch of time but the problem that he runs into is loading the folder with all the pictures in the jar file. We have created the manifest.mf file and we have created the jar file but it does not run. I have been using [this website](http://en.newinstance.it/2012/04/17/self-executing-jar-files/) as a reference

I have looked at a lot of stuff about this but the problem is I don't know much about it and most people create these things with simple programs like hello world. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated because I spent a lot of time on this program and if I can't run it on other computers than its pretty much useless to me. The images are located in a folder called Pictures which is inside the bin folder of the eclipse project.

The code where I upload the images looks like

```
for(int i = 0; i < pic.length-1; i++)
    {
        pic[i] = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Pictures/" + i +".JPG")); // Fills array with pictures

    }
```

The rest of my code looks like

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AubsGUI extends JFrame 
{
int size = 20;
JLabel label;
JButton prevPic, prevQuote,changeQuote;
JTextArea text, text2;
ImageIcon pic[] = new ImageIcon[size];
JPanel panel;
int count = 0;
int i = 0;
int oldIndex = 0;
static ArrayList<String> quotes = new ArrayList<String>();
public AubsGUI() // constructor 
{
    panel = new JPanel(); // Creates a JPanel
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(randomColorForBackground()); // Sets the background of that panel to a random color
    add(panel); // Adds panel to screen

    text2 = new JTextArea("Click the image for a new one");
    text2.setBounds(630,10,300,300);
    panel.add(text2);
    text2.setFont(new Font("FatFrank",Font.BOLD,16));
    panel.setBackground(randomColorForBackground());    
    text2.setForeground(randomColorForFont());
    text2.setOpaque(false);
    text2.setEditable(false);

    for(int i = 0; i < pic.length-1; i++)
    {
        pic[i] = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/Pictures/" + i +".JPG")); // Fills array with pictures
    }

    label = new JLabel(); // Creates a JLabel
    label.setIcon(picture()); // Sets picture to the label
    label.setBounds(10,10,600,700);
    panel.add(label); // Adds the label to the panel

    changePic e = new changePic(); 
    label.addMouseListener(e);
    panel.addMouseListener(e);

    prevPic = new JButton("Click for Previous Picture");
    prevPic.setBounds(1000,0,185,30);
    prevPic.addActionListener(new previousPic());
    prevPic.setForeground(randomColorForBackground());
    panel.add(prevPic);

    getQuotes();
    text = new JTextArea(quotes.get(getIndex()));
    text.setBounds(650,100,200,200);
    panel.add(text);
    panel.setBackground(randomColorForBackground());
    text.setFont(new Font("FatFrank",Font.BOLD,16));
    text.setForeground(randomColorForFont());
    text.setOpaque(false);
    text.setEditable(false);
    changeQuote = new JButton("Click For New Quote");
    changeQuote.setBounds(1000,20,185,30);
    changeQuote.addActionListener(new changeQuote());
    changeQuote.setForeground(randomColorForBackground());
    panel.add(changeQuote);

    prevQuote = new JButton("Click for Previous Quote");
}
public ImageIcon picture()
{
    if (i >= pic.length) 
    {
        i = 0;
    }
    if(count > 1)
    {
        oldIndex = i--;
    }
    Random flipCoin = new Random(); 
    i = flipCoin.nextInt(pic.length-1); // Makes i a random # between 0 & 20 
    ImageIcon icon = pic[i]; // Sets icon to be a random picture in the array
    Image image = icon.getImage(); // Transforms icon from an ImageIcon to an Image so it can be resized
    Image tempImg = image.getScaledInstance( 600, 700,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH ) ; // Resizes the image
    icon = new ImageIcon(tempImg); // Transforms the Image back to an ImageIcon
    return  icon; // Returns the random picture
}
public ImageIcon picAt()
{
    ImageIcon icon = pic[oldIndex];
    Image image = icon.getImage();
    Image tempImg = image.getScaledInstance( 600, 700,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH );
    icon = new ImageIcon(tempImg);
    return  icon; 
}
public void getQuotes()
{
    URL url = getClass().getResource("Quotes/Quotes.txt");
    try{    
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(url.getPath()));

        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {   
            quotes.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        scan.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}
public Color randomColorForFont()
{
    int r = (int)(Math.random() *256);
    int g = (int)(Math.random() *256);
    int b = (int)(Math.random() *256);
    return (new Color(r, g, b).brighter());
}
public Color randomColorForBackground()
{
    int r = (int)(Math.random() *256);
    int g = (int)(Math.random() *256);
    int b = (int)(Math.random() *256);
    return (new Color(r, g, b).darker());
}
public int getIndex()
{
    int index;
    index = (int)(Math.random()*quotes.size());
    return index;
}

public class changePic implements MouseListener
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        text2.setForeground(randomColorForFont());
        label.setIcon(picture());   
        panel.setBackground(randomColorForBackground());
        count++;

    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
}
public class changeQuote implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent q) 
    {

        text.setText(quotes.get(getIndex())); // Sets the quote in text area
        text.setFont(new Font("FatFrank",Font.BOLD,16));
        text.setForeground(randomColorForFont()); // Sets the fonts to white
        text.setLineWrap(true); // Lets the string be broken up if it's to long
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true); // Won't let text.setLineWrap(true) break up the words
        text.setOpaque(false);
        text.setEditable(false); // Won't let the text area be edited
        changeQuote.setForeground(randomColorForBackground());
        panel.setBackground(randomColorForBackground());    
    }
}
public class previousPic implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent p) 
    {
        if(count > 0)
        {
            prevPic.setForeground(randomColorForBackground());
            label.setIcon(picAt());
            panel.setBackground(randomColorForBackground());
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String args [])
{
    AubsGUI aubs = new AubsGUI(); // creates an object aubs from class AubsGUi  
    aubs.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // allows window to close and program to end  
    aubs.setSize(new Dimension(1200, 1000));
    aubs.setVisible(true); // allows you to see window while program runs
    aubs.setTitle("title ");
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please share the code you are using to load images as well as explain how they are packaged? Are they inside the jar or in a folder?

Comment: They are located in a folder which is inside the bin folder of the eclipse project

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html for an alternate approach to packaing.

Comment: You are loading the images from the classpath, but my guess is that when you run the jar the images are not on the classpath. Either change the code to load images from a directory that can be specified or bundle the images in the jar

Comment: How do I bundle the images in the jar? I'm very new to this stuff so i'm sorry if am asking stupid question.

Comment: I read through some of the stuff in the link that hotzst posted but a lot of it is over my head.

Comment: Just put the images in a folder next to your source. (inside your project)

Comment: Ok I did that. Now I have created my jar file inside my bin folder (idk if that matters) how to I add that folder to my jar file?

Comment: You're using a null layout, so the GUI may not fit on another computer's display.

Comment: yea but that shouldn't matter right now for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your issue, since your description is not very clear.

Probably you are passing the images as a reference to your local files, instead of adding them to the Jar file.

It's exactly the same if you have a shortcut for a game in your PC, and you try to copy that shortcut to another computer. The game will not work.

You need to add the images to your jar package.

Comment: I I think I did this but its still not working. How do I do this